# Extracting values from each cell using a loop and printing in another tab

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following:

```
Sub loopCell()

Dim cell As range
For Each cell In range("p10:p200")

Next cell

End Sub
```

I want to extract the value of every cell that my loop iterates. After that, I want to print values in another sheet and store the values in a variable/array.

Comment: extract to where ? an array ? `tab1` and `tab2` are `"Sheet1"` and `"Sheet2"` ?

Comment: From sheet1 to sheet2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why need a loop for this?

You can directly copy/assign the values. See this example

```
'~~> Change `A1:A190` to the relevant range when you want the output...
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A190").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P10:P1200").Value
```

or

```
'~~> Change `A1` to the relevant range when you want the output...
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P10:P1200").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

**EDIT**

As per user's updated request, he wants to store the values as well. In such a scenario, you can store the values to an array and then from there you can output it to the relevant sheet

Here is an example

```
Dim MyAr As variant

MyAr = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("P10:P1200").Value
```

If you want selected values from the array then loop through the array and then output it to the relevant sheet.

```
'~~> looping through the array
For i = LBound(MyAr) To Ubound(MyAr)
    Debug.Print MyAr(i,1)
Next i
```

If you would like to output the complete array to the worksheet in one go then you can do this as well

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(Ubound(MyAr),1).Value = MyAr
```

Comment: Later I will need to store that values.

Comment: Where have you mentioned that in the question?

Comment: wow , typing faster than light speed ! do you have all answers already ready and categorized :)

Comment: I didn't added for clarification.

Comment: I have updated the above post. You may have to refresh it